# How do you inherit FirebaseAuth class in a new class?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class FireAuth extends FirebaseAuth{
      FireAuth({Key? key}) : super.instanceFor(app: app);
...
```

I want to be able to build my own class based on the FirebaseAuth class
but I keep getting this error:

> The generative constructor 'FirebaseAuth FirebaseAuth.instanceFor({required FirebaseApp app})' is expected, but a factory was found.
> Try calling a different constructor of the superclass, or making the called constructor not be a factory constructor.

Comment: try extension function to enhance the functionality of FirbeaseAuth Class

Comment: thanks, @FaiiziiAwan, that seems to do the trick. Ill add the solution below

Answer (score 1):

To get around the issue with inheriting the FirebaseAuth. I have used the extension function instead of the extends. So it looks like this

```
extension FireAuth on FirebaseAuth {
   ...
```

no need for a constructor now